# How to get QuerySet values separately?

Tags: python, django

How I can to get values  from QuerySet separately? The result of my QuerySet now is 
 `<QuertSet[<value: 5>, <value:90>]>`
How I can get 5, 90 to separate variable ?

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: Tell us how did you got `<QuertSet[<value: 5>, <value:90>]>`. Post that django query you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can acheive it. For example:

```
for item in queryset:
    print(item.field_name)
```

or using [**`values_list()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
for item in queryset.values_list('field_name', flat=True):
    print(item)
```

If you want the first two values of a queryset, then do this:

```
values = queryset.values_list('field_name', flat=True)

variable_one = values[0]

variable_two = values[1]
```

Comment: thank you! Now I now that I can use all operations for array when I deals with QuerySet results